# Expected output to file 'numbers.txt' did not meet the requirements

Tags: kotlin, append, file-handling, writefile, mutablelist

Create a program that ask a user to type positive integers. Each positive integer is saved to a file called numbers.txt. When a user types -1, the program reads the file, and add numbers to a list. Finally, the program prints the count and the average of typed numbers from a list. If the typed integer is not positive, the program prints "The number must be positive" message.

So far, my program is as follows:

```
import java.util.*
import java.io.File

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
    var counter = 0
    while(true){
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var file = File("numbers.txt")
    println("Type a positive integer (-1 to exit):")
    var input_num = reader.nextInt()
        if (input_num >= 0) {
            list.add(input_num)
            counter++
        }
        else if (input_num < -1){
            println("The number must be positive")
        }
        else if (input_num == -1){
            break
        }
    }
    println("You typed $counter numbers.")
    println("The average is ${list.average()}.")
}
```

The output is working as expected 1) counter displays the desirable number and 2) the average of the list is also displayed correctly.

Although, my issue is that no numbers were added to the actual .txt file. I am sorry for any mistake made on by behalf this is my first post and I am completely new to Kotlin language. Any feedback is very appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? As you say, your program does not fulfil all the stated requirements, in that it doesn't write the numbers to a file, nor read them back from the file. If you're asking how to do either or both of those, then there's a lot of extraneous material that could be trimmed from the question and from your code. Otherwise, please explain what you're actually asking.

Comment: Hi& welcome! 1. `while(true)` should move after `println("Type a positiv..`.2. `if (input_num >= 0)` ..you should write to `file`!(? As i understand... it's unused so far.)

Comment: @xerx593 Thank you for your help.  I was so confused earlier that I didn't see that it was a matter of line order. 
At the end the program was simply working as this:

+added in first condition( (input_num >= 0) ) the following: file.appendText(input_num.toString()+"\n")

much appreciated!